# Linear Algebra - Subsets involving calculus (possibly)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let $V = C([a,b])$ be a vector space and let $S$ be a subset of $V$ defined as 
$$S = \left\{f \in V \colon \int_a^b f(x) dx = 0\right\}.$$
￼￼Determine if $S$ is a subspace of $V$ , and if so, prove it.

*I apologize for writing out some of the math but my symbols wouldn't work. I realize I have to prove that axioms 1 and 6 follow in order to consider it a sub space, but not sure how to pick an arbitrary function to prove this. Should I just introduce the integral of f(x) = 0 and integral of g(x) = 0, then follow up with stating int. f(x)dx + int. g(x)dx =0? Thanks for you help.

Comment: That $\;V\;$ is not *a vector space*, but a well defined and rather important one: **the** vector space of all continuous real functions defined on the closed interval $\;[a,b]\;$ .

Comment: good catch, but I still understood what it was asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $f$ and $g$ that you choose as arbitrary functions should **NOT** be identically zero.  They should just have the property that $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b g(x)dx =0$.

Then to prove or disprove closure under addition, you need to either confirm or provide a counterexample to the statement: $\int_a^b\ (f+g)(x)dx=0$.

Comment: Ok I am following. So then in order to prove it, would I just split it up into two separate integrals? and then show that according to the property previously established, they both go to 0?

Comment: Yep.  That's how it works.  Then you just need to prove(/disprove) closure under scalar multiplication and you're done. :)

Comment: Nice! thanks I really appreciate your help. I guess my professor wanted us to think we had to use calculus. I guess to disprove it you would need to. Well thanks

Comment: To be fair you do need to know a little bit of calculus.  You need to know that $\int_a^b (f+g)(x)dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx + \int_a^b g(x)dx$, provided that all of these integrals exist.  You also need to know that the integrals on the RHS *do* exist because $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on a closed and bounded subinterval of $\Bbb R$.  But yeah -- you don't need to actually *calculate* any integrals or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\begin{align}& 0\in S\\{}\\&\forall\,f,g\in S\;,\;\;\forall\,k\in\Bbb R;,\;\;\int_a^b(kf(x)+g(x))dx=0\end{align}$$